# Is it possible to use a Matrix class to get unrotated dimensions of an object or do I have to do it manually?

Tags: matrices, geometry

I have an object that has a rotation applied to it and I want to get the pre transformed values.

Here is the dimensions where the element has rotation applied and the dimensions after the rotation is set to none.

```
Bounds at 90 rotation: {
 height     30
 width      0
 x          25
 y          10
}
transform at 90 rotation: matrix(0,1,-1,0,25,10)
set rotation delta: -90
item.rotation: 0
transform at rotation 0: matrix(1,0,0,1,10,25)
Bounds at rotation 0: {
 height     0
 width      30
 x          10
 y          25
}
```

In the past I was able to use an API to set the rotation to 0 and then read the updated bounds. The API has a bug that is preventing using that method so I need to find the dimensions manually.

I have access to a Matrix class and it looks like it has some methods that may help but if not my matrix math is really rusty. Is there an equation I can use to get dimensions at an arbitrary rotation?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var bounds = element.bounds;
var rotationDelta = 0 - element.rotation; // -90
var matrix = new Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, bounds.x, bounds.y); // matrix(1,0,0,1,25,10)
matrix.rotate(rotationDelta); // matrix(0,-1,1,0,25,10)
```

Calling rotate doesn't change the x or y values or show how to get a transformed width or height.

Comment: Well if the rotation is always $90$ degrees, that's obviously trivial. I assume it isn't, though. Regardless, I don't think this question is appropriate for this site. Not only is it a question about programming, it's not even about a specific library. How can we possibly know if this Matrix class does what you want?

Comment: I can remove the code. It's about finding out if it's possible to get a size and space in cartesian coordinates space if you have the width height, x y and rotation values. It's probably impossible though so never mind.

Comment: Rotation by $\theta$ is given by $\left(\begin{array}{ll}\cos(\theta)&\sin(\theta)\\\sin(-\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{array}\right)$ I believe, possibly with the sign reversed. It should be easy to find online.

Comment: I can do a search but what terms would I search for? Yeah, if it was 90' degrees angles it would be done :)

Comment: The sign is in fact reversed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix